# neo4j: cypher match nodes by multiple lables OR clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have computer nodes, company nodes(IBM, HP, DELL etc),

IS it possible to fetch all computers that are manufactured by IBM OR HP, **without using WHERE clause**?

Below cyphers are giving syntax error:

```
MATCH (c:computer)<-[:MANUFACTURED_BY]-(comp:HP|IBM) return c
MATCH (c:computer)<-[:MANUFACTURED_BY]-(comp:HP|:IBM) return c
MATCH (c:computer)<-[:MANUFACTURED_BY]-(comp:HP OR :IBM) return c
```

Comment: The first query that you have is a valid Cypher syntax, starting from neo4j version 5.0. I believe your version is less than 5.0 (https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#label-expression-match-or-expression), that's why you are seeing this error. If that's the case where clause is your only choice

Comment: thank you, I have asked another question, see if you could help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75993856/neo4j-cypher-case-and-union

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UNION` operator in Cypher

```
MATCH (c:computer)<-[:MANUFACTURED_BY]-(comp:HP)
RETURN c
UNION
MATCH (c:computer)<-[:MANUFACTURED_BY]-(comp:IBM)
RETURN c
```