# neo4j: cypher case and union

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are using neo4j v4.

I have USER, COMPUTER, COMPANY nodes(IBM, HP, DELL etc),

How can I make the HP_IBM case work(i.e. when u.preference is HP_IBM, I want the computers manufactured by both HP and IBM)?

```
MATCH (u:USER {id: 101})
RETURN  
CASE u.preference 
WHEN 'HP'    THEN  [(n:computer)-[r: MANUFACTURED_BY]->(c:HP) | n]
WHEN 'IBM'   THEN [(n:computer)-[r:ASSEMBELED_BY]->(c:IBM) | n] 
WHEN 'DELL'   THEN [(n:computer)-[r:ASSEMBELED_BY]->(c:DELL) | n] 
WHEN 'HP_IBM' THEN xxxxxxx END
AS result;
```

Any other queries/approaches are welcome!

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the exact use-case that are you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: when user preference is HP_IBM, I want to return all COMPUTERs by HP and IBM!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your schema can be modeled in a better way. Instead of having company names as Node Labels, you can store them as a part of the company node property let's say `name`. And instead of storing preferences as a concatenated String, you can store user-preferred companies in an array, like this: `["HP", "IBM"]`, now your cypher query becomes fairly simple, like this:

```
MATCH (u:USER {id: 101})
MATCH (n:computer)-[:MANUFACTURED_BY]->(c:Company)
WHERE c.name IN u.preferences 
RETURN n;
```

If you want to keep the current schema itself, then try this:

```
MATCH (u:USER {id: 101})
RETURN  
CASE u.preference 
WHEN 'HP'    THEN  [(n:computer)-[r: MANUFACTURED_BY]->(c:HP) | n]
WHEN 'IBM'   THEN [(n:computer)-[r:ASSEMBELED_BY]->(c:IBM) | n] 
WHEN 'HP_IBM' THEN [(n:computer)-[r]->(c) WHERE ANY(x IN split(c.preference, '_') WHERE x IN labels(c)) | n] END
AS result;
```

Notice, that I have removed the relationship type from the path match because your relationship type varies with the company, so if your computer nodes are linked with the company, via a lot of distinct relationship types. This query might not work.

Comment: Sry, can't change the model! question is about how to return union of 2 types in a switch case?

Comment: BTW, even if you want to keep your current model, you can follow the guidelines of this answer to do so. I think it is better than the switch case approach, just split your string and use set-intersection instead of `IN`

Comment: sry, updated the question, in case of HP there is MANUFACTURED_BY relation b/w computer and company. In case of IBM, there is ASSEMBELED_BY relation b/w computer and company.  In case of DELL, there is ASSEMBELED_BY relation b/w computer and company. now, I want to fill the cypher clause HP_IBM case?

Comment: Hey, it worked like a charm! how do you know that WHERE clause can be appended right at the end? can you share some better resources for cypher?

Comment: You can go this documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/ @Arjun.